# different ways of enforcing association relationship

Tags: ruby, uml, associations

For an association between two objects:

If I have an "Office" object and a "Person" object. I would model that as an association and I've come up with the below example code as a means of enforcing it.

But looking at it, there are a lot of things I would like to be more comfortable with.

**First question:** The Office object is in fact a class. I've done this because I would only ever want one office - and it feels wrong to be instantiating it. But I feel like I'm missing something in describing the relationship between an instantiated person and a "static" class as an association?

**Second question:** I've enforced the association between the two objects by passing one of the objects to the other. Is this a typical way of associating two classes?

```
class Office
  @log = []
  @occupants = []

  def self.occupants
    @occupants
  end

  def self.log
    @log
  end

  def self.log_entry(person)
    if @occupants << person
      @log << "#{person.name} entered Office: #{Time.now}"
    end
  end  

  def self.log_exit(person)
    if @occupants.delete(person)
      @log << "#{person.name} exited Office: #{Time.now}"
    end
  end
end


class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

zach = Person.new('Zach')
bill = Person.new('Bill')

Office.log_entry(zach)
Office.log_entry(bill)
Office.log_exit(zach)

puts Office.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML thinking relations are between instances and not between classes and also not between classes and instances. But there are cases where it would be natural to have a relation between two classes or between a class and and instance. Let's take your person/office example. 
The class of offices could be named Offices and a single instance Office
So there would be a natural 1:n relation between Offices and Office.
The class of persons could be named Persons and a single instance Person. So there would be a natural 1:n relation between Persons and Person. The Office-Person relation ship would be what you get when you draw a line between Offices and Persons in an UML diagram.

1. The "wrong" feeling comes from the explanation above. Your  Offices would have just one Office. There are multiple person instances linked to that one office which is perfectly o.k.
2. For a 1:1 and 1:N relation it usually sufficient if one instance knows the other. For 1:1 a "double" linking is also easily possible. In your office:person relationship each person "knows" the office it belongs to that is why you pass the office instance for the person to remember. Keeping a list of persons belonging to an office is possible but redundant as long as there is some means of doing a query "who are the persons that belong to this office..."

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late reply. In this case I want (for no other reason than for the sake of learning) to map the building to a class schema. So for example I might be looking at House1::Office, House1::Bathroom, etc. In this case I would only ever need the class and the instantiated object. Would this be a silly way to program? To me this is kind of how I imagine an ORM to function, where classes represent tables (the rooms). In a way this seems it would be almost a document database?

Comment: @ZachSmith - please send me a personal message via one of my contact options. After working your example out we can than post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really UML related, except you use the term Association. Anyhow, I'll try to answer it.

1. If I understand you correctly you want your `Office` class to be a singleton (only one instance). In UML you could visualize that by applying a `<<singleton>>` stereotype or by inheriting from a class you call `Singleton` (that's a bit a matter of taste and circumstances). But you would always need an instance since in real world a class becomes an instances. Only that has bits and bytes. The class is just its concept.
2. It is irrelevant from an UML perspective how you realize your association. There it's just a concept that there is some kind of relation between both. So whether you create an instance via `new` and hold that or you get it passed on does not matter.

I can add the UML diagram for your classes if you need that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in Ruby the classes themselves are objects so the class as defined above works as an object and you wouldn't need to instantiate it to use it. I want to use the class more as a namespace in this case, and not a template for an object really. I guess it's more like an ORM representation of a table actually. Except that perhaps you wouldn't store data in the namespace itself... but rather in a file or a database

Comment: I know Ruby and have modeled a couple of things there using UML. You are likely talking about the scaffolding you can do in Ruby. But you mix up things. A class is an abstract concept and an instance is the life representation of it. A Ruby class still is a concept. You should think about MVC which Ruby implements rather perfectly.